# Alertmanager as alternate context (url/alertmanager) in ingress on k8s showing 404 not found

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I have setup Prometheus grafana stack (helm charts, version 43.3.0) on kubernetes. The version is of prometheus used is v2.40.5. Alertmanager is v0.25.0. Installation is success.
Able to access alertmanager when exposed the service type as LoadBalancer.
When trying to access alertmanager (using existing nginx ingress and changing alertmanager service to clusterIP) and the path set is /alertmanager results in 404 not found.

Ingress.yaml

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: ingress
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - admin'
spec:
tls:
- hosts:
- example.com
secretName: tls-secret
rules:
host: example.com
http:
paths:
backend:
service:
name: alertmanager-service
port:
number: 80
path: /alertmanager
pathType: Prefix
```

Is there any way where I could use the alertmanager service in the existing ingress.